# Linq query matching two dictionaries in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, json, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have json objects in a Cosmos container where a part if the object is known and I've also got indexes I need to query. These are dictionaries with unknown keys. What I need to do is supply a dictionary with keys and values and get those objects that has the matching keys and values in "indexes".

```
        Dictionary<string, object> mySuppliedQueryIndexes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        mySuppliedQueryIndexes.Add("Customer", "Foo");
        mySuppliedQueryIndexes.Add("AnotherIndex", "Bar");

        using (FeedIterator<ArchiveQueryResult> setIterator = cont.GetItemLinqQueryable<ArchiveQueryResult>()
                 // Indexes
                 .Where(b => b.indexes.Keys.All(k => mySuppliedQueryIndexes.ContainsKey(k) && mySuppliedQueryIndexes[k] == b.keys[k]))
                 .ToFeedIterator())
```

An object (cut down) like the ones I'd like to get:

```json
{
    "id": "DUxLTg5OTUyNDFfMjUvMDYvMjBfMjYvMDkvMTlfMDUvMTIvMTlfMjYvMDYvMjBfQXhlbCBVZWJlbHM_",
    "definition": "defId",
    "partitionkey": "defPartition",
    "tenant": "template",
    "environment": "Test",
    "expiry": "2032-01-29T07:47:28",
    "indexes": {
        "Customer": "Foo",
        "AnotherIndex": "Bar",
        "Example": "example",
    }
}
```

The above is what I'm trying so far, but when running it I get *"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: 'Method 'All' is not supported.'"*. If I'm trying with Any that seems supported I instead get the error *"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq.DocumentQueryException: 'Method 'ContainsKey' is not supported.'*"

How do you query a dictionary in Cosmos or what would be the correct/smart way to query multiple, unknown valuepairs in a json? A typical scenario is a maximum of maybe three to five different indexes, so no huge amount.

There's hundreds of thousands objects in the container.

Comment: It might help to edit your question with some sample data, to help clarify what you're asking. My *guess* is that it's about finding specific keys within a document. If so: You cannot just get a list of property keys within a document or set of documents: You'd have to pull the documents and enumerate them yourself.

Comment: I've added sample data for the kind of documents I'm querying. "indexes" are dynamic valuepairs, and I need to query the container with some or all of these matching valuepairs. It's not possible to use a class to query the indexes since these are dynamically created by the user.